# passed "from pyfiglet import Figlet" but when I try to run the script from terminal get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'

Tags: python, terminal

So I'm trying to import pyfiglet and run the script from terminal, However whenever I try I get this error. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'. I have pyfiglet installed already and I'm not too sure why I'd be getting this error. I'm using pycharm and currently using a mac. any ideas?

tried to run a script from terminal, got error module not found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.